# Cannot change file name with system() in C (windows)

Tags: c, windows, file, system

I am trying to get the HDD serial key of a windows PC using *system()* command and save that number in a text (.txt) file with a file name that user chooses. Everything is working fine before the *system()* command, but the *system()* command is NOT changing the file name,that is, instead of naming the file after the user choice, it is just naming it after "contract_file_name" with no extension. For example: if I give file name: blahblah , it's supposed to create a text file with the name "blahblah.txt" (containing HDD serial Key), but instead it's creating a file with "contract_file_name".

Here is code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char contract_file_name[100];
FILE *fp1 ;

filename:
printf("Please Give an APPROPRIATE name for SENDER-RECEIVER CONTRACT file. Please Don't use any .txt extension\nFILE NAME: ");
gets(contract_file_name);
strcat(contract_file_name,".txt");
if((fp1=fopen(contract_file_name,"r")))
    {
        printf("A Contract File with %s already EXITS.Please Choose another name\n".contract_file_name);
        goto filename;
    }
    else
    {

        fp1= fopen(contract_file_name,"w");
        fprintf(fp1,"$Sender: %s\n",getenv("USERNAME"));
        fclose(fp1);
        system("wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber >> contract_file_name"); //Having problem in this line,I think.
        fp1 = fopen("contract_file_name","a");
        fprintf(fp1,"\n");
        fclose(fp1);
    }
return 0;
}
```

I can feel that the problem is with my method *system()* command, But can't find any solution.Can anyone please suggest me how to FIX this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The `system()` function is **not** a command prompt. It only runs programs but does not do string replacements and I/O redirections.

Comment: @iBug Thanks , didn't know that, Any alternative suggestion?

Comment: @iBug who says it doesn't do redirections?! it is redirecting for OP

Comment: @iBug: `system` launches a command interpreter and it actually does variable expansion and redirection. Technically OP could use `putenv` and  do a variable expansion. However I strongly discourage doing so.

Comment: @iBug, `system` executes `%ComSpec% /c [command line]`, which of course allows environment variable expansion and standard I/O redirection. I don't know what you tested that led you to conclude otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have `contract_file_name` is a literal string in your `system` call. You have to put the value of the variable in the string first, something like

```
char tmp[100+50];
sprintf(tmp, "wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber >> %s",  contract_file_name);
system(tmp);
```

You should also limit what you read into `contract_file_name` to 99 characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but please tell me about `char tmp[_MAX_PATH+20 ]` and the `system(tmp)`

Comment: `tmp` is a temporary variable for the intermediate string created by `sprintf`. The length has to be long enough to contain all of the characters. In your case `contract_file_name` can be 100 chars long, and I added 20 for the rest of the string (which was wrong, it's more like 50). In Windows one usually uses MAX_PATH instead of 100 for file paths, that's why I wrote MAX_PATH first.

Comment: NOT WORKING... Program keeps crashing !!

Comment: sorry, I forgot `tmp` in the `sprintf` call

Comment: You'd better use `snprintf` for better safety.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the `system` function (which you shouldn't be using for this task anyway), but with your misunderstanding how string substitution works.

You have a variable `contract_file_name` of type "array of 100 char" and apparently expect every occurance of "contract_file_name" inside a string to automatically being replaced. This is called "variable expansion" and is in fact supported in some languages. Most notably shell and Perl. However you actually have to mark the variables in a string for replacement (usually by prepending a `$` sign). **That does not work in C!** C is a very frugal language and doesn't come with that feature.

Anyway your program immediately reads back the file and hence using a fixed filename or a filename at all is a bad idea anyway (think about what might happen if several instances of your program get run at the same time; can you prove that all parts in play are idempotent? probably not).

Instead you should run `wmic` with `popen`. With `popen` the output of `wmic` is written to a FIFO which you can read directy as if it were a file, without a file ever being written to a disk: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx

Comment: But I need to write the in the disk

Comment: @Md.FakruddinGazzaliFahim: Then you either have to format (using `sprintf`) an appropriate command or, and that's what I recommend, read from the `popen`-ed fifo and write to a file you `fopen`-ed; that's what the `>>` inside a system call does. But doing so yourself has the benefit, that you do not depend on the quirks of the command interpreter launched by `system`.